# How to add scroll or view my card which is placed below the order now and track order card

Tags: android

i have written a code in android studio

on making a card i am able to place it below my order now and track order card
but i am not able to view it as my screen does not scrolls

please help me with the code have been trying to get an answer from a long time now..!!!

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
   android:id="@+id/activity_main"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent"
   android:orientation="vertical"
   android:background="@color/bg_screen9"

tools:context="com.example.rishabmehrotra.foodie.MainActivity">

<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/view_pager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/macd"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="400dp"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_above="@+id/relativeLayout">

</RelativeLayout>

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="200dp"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:id="@+id/relativeLayout">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ord"
        android:padding="15dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="169dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="169dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="13dp"
        android:id="@+id/imageView4" />


    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:src="@drawable/track"
        android:padding="15dp"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/imageView4"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="171dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="171dp" />
</RelativeLayout>


<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/relativeLayout">


<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/cv"
    >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="16dp"
        >

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/person_photo"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
            />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/person_name"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/person_photo"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:textSize="30sp"
            />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/person_age"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/person_photo"
            android:layout_below="@+id/person_name"
            />

    </RelativeLayout>

</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Your layout seems to be massively complex. How can you have a CardView, a ViewPager and so many RelativeLayout in the same view?  You should probably try to redesign it.

Comment: any suggestions in what to do as i am new in android programming and i need to finish this module ASAP!

Comment: I don't know exactly what you want to achieve. Maybe you should update your question with the design of the final result.

Comment: Eselfar i got my problem sorted out a few minutes ago as u said i modified my layout THanks for the suggestion :)